# Consecutively changed value of parameter in JMeter HTTP Request

Tags: jmeter

I want to create a test plan for testing a given web, using JMeter. There are two parameters in this test: X and Y.

Each loop, I give a random number from 0 to 50 `${__Random(0,50,)}` as parameter X, and then give Y the values as follows: `Y=[0,10,20...50]` consecutively (X remains the same).

I used a counter here, but I got a different X each time. And user parameters don't seem suitable for this problem. Or maybe I just don't know how to use them correctly.

Are there any methods to solve this problem? I'm new to this tool, so it may be something basic.

Thanks in advance:D

Here is the screenshot of my test plan:
[image]

Comment: Show you test plan structure through a screen shot or textual representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a csv data set as child of test plan and put in File you will reference from it

```
 0
 10
 20
 30
 40
 50
```

Set y as var
And use ${y} as Y value

Comment: Thanks at first.I set ${__Random(0,50,)} as the value of parameter X in Http Request and y as value of Y as the method above.But when Y changes from 0 to 50 consecutively, X changes again. In my test plan, I want to make one value of X with 6 consecutive value of Y [0,10,20...50]. So I think there is still some details I need to modify.

Comment: Finally, I added a User Definition Variables as a son of Thread Group and did as what you told, it works.--Test Plan;---Class C;----User Defined Variables,----CSV Data Set Config,----HTTP Request. Thanks again:D